# Canvas not drawing on mobile chrome but will draw on safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, canvas

I have the following script that takes an image and draws a canvas based on an images background colour (the image is loaded from a database using php), I require it to be responsive and it is working on mobile safari but not on chrome:

At certain resolutions the canvas will fallback to a square from a wave, and also resizes whenever the window width is changed (added this for mobile device rotation).

I must note that this script works on mobile chrome on pages where i am not getting the colour from an image and I am setting that colour statically, leading me to think that is an issue with the canvas not drawing due to the image not being loaded yet.

```
<script>

    function drawCatWave () {
        window.onload = function () {
            var catImg = new Image();
            catImg.src = "/product_images/<?php echo $row_category['logo_colour']; ?>";
            var context;
            context = document.getElementById('cat-image').getContext('2d');
            context.drawImage(catImg, 20, 20, 130, 100);
            pixData = (context.getImageData(20, 20, 1, 1).data);

            rgb1 = pixData[0].toString();
            rgb2 = pixData[1].toString();
            rgb3 = pixData[2].toString();
            rgb4 = pixData[3].toString();

            var rgbString = rgb1 + "," + rgb2 + "," + rgb3 + "," + rgb4;
            var rgb = "rgba(" + rgbString + ")";
            $('.cat-prod-box h2').css("color", rgb);


            console.log(rgb1, rgb2, rgb3);
            canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
            var parent = document.getElementById("cat-banner-wave");
            ctx = canvas.getContext("2d")
            canvas.width = parent.offsetWidth;
            canvas.height = parent.offsetHeight;
            var actWidth = canvas.width;
            var actHeight = canvas.height;

            canvas.height = 380;
            ctx.lineWidth = 6;
            ctx.strokeStyle = "rgba(" + rgbString + ")";
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.moveTo(0, 70);
            ctx.bezierCurveTo((actWidth / 2), -200, (actWidth / 3), 445, actWidth, 100);
            ctx.bezierCurveTo(actWidth, 333, actWidth, 333, actWidth, 333);
            ctx.bezierCurveTo(0, 333, 0, 333, 0, 333);
            ctx.closePath();
            ctx.fillStyle = rgb;

            ctx.fill();
            ctx.stroke();



        };
    }

    function drawCatSquare () {
        window.onload = function () {
            var catImg = new Image();
            catImg.src = "/product_images/<?php echo $row_category['logo_colour']; ?>";
            var context;
            context = document.getElementById('cat-image').getContext('2d');
            context.drawImage(catImg, 20, 20, 130, 100);
            pixData = (context.getImageData(20, 20, 1, 1).data);

            rgb1 = pixData[0].toString();
            rgb2 = pixData[1].toString();
            rgb3 = pixData[2].toString();
            rgb4 = pixData[3].toString();

            var rgbString = rgb1 + "," + rgb2 + "," + rgb3 + "," + rgb4;
            var rgb = "rgba(" + rgbString + ")";

            $('.cat-prod-box h2').css("color", rgb);


            console.log(rgb1, rgb2, rgb3);
            canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
            var parent = document.getElementById("cat-banner-wave");
            ctx = canvas.getContext("2d")
            canvas.width = parent.offsetWidth;
            canvas.height = parent.offsetHeight;
            var actWidth = canvas.width;
            var actHeight = canvas.height;

            canvas.height = 380;
            ctx.lineWidth = 6;
            ctx.strokeStyle = "rgba(" + rgbString + ")";
            ctx.rect(0, 0, actWidth, actHeight);
            ctx.fillStyle = rgb;

            ctx.fill();
            ctx.stroke();


        };
    }

    $(document).ready(function () {
        if($(this).width() > 500){
            drawCatWave();
        }else{

            drawCatSquare();
        }
    });

    $(window).resize(function () {
        if ($(this).width() > 500) {
            drawCatWave();
        } else {
            drawCatSquare();
        }
    });



</script>
```

Comment: that is an issue with the canvas not drawing due to the image not being loaded yet

Comment: hmm, I thought that window.load was ensuring the canvas wasn't drawing until the whole window had loaded, does mobile chrome handle this differently for some reason?

Comment: yes the window is loaded on window.load. Then the script executes, and ask for an image load with an .src assignment. So the result will depend on the way cache is handled on the Browser. ( and just try !)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Issues

There are a few issues here:

- You are placing window.onload inside your two functions
- You are not waiting for the image to load
- You will get a race-condition related to draw order on the canvas

## Solutions

First off, place all your code inside the `window.onload` instead:

```
window.onload = function() {

    function drawCatWave() {
        ...
    }

    function drawCatSquare() {
        ...
    }

}
```

The window.onload is invoked when the DOM and images existing in the DOM has loaded. But as you are dynamically creating an image element in your code *after* this has been invoked it won't apply. You will have to handle the image loading manually (see below).

An alternative to using window.onload is to place your script at the bottom of the page before the body close tag.

Second, as mentioned, you need to wait for the image to load before proceeding. This is because the image loading is asynchronous so while the browser is connecting and downloading the image data your code continues with the other instructions. If the image isn't loaded in time the `drawImage()` method will abort and result is a "blank" canvas.

In general you do this to handle image loading:

```
var image = new Image;
image.onload = callbackFunction;
image.src = '...';
```

So in this case:

```
function drawCatWave () {
    var catImg = new Image();
    catImg.onload = catDone;
    catImg.src = "/product_images/<?php echo $row_category['logo_colour']; ?>";

    function catDone() {
        var context;
        context = document.getElementById('cat-image').getContext('2d');
        context.drawImage(catImg, 20, 20, 130, 100);
        ... etc ...
    }
}
```

Now if you want to draw onto the same canvas you need to chain the calls or you can get into a race-condition depending on which image loaded first.

To handle this situation extend your functions with a callback parameter:

```
    function drawCatWave(callback) {
        ...
    }

    function drawCatSquare(callback) {
        ...
    }
```

and lets modify the code inside the functions (showing only for one):

```
function drawCatWave (callback) {
    var catImg = new Image();
    catImg.onload = catDone;
    catImg.src = "/product_images/<?php echo $row_category['logo_colour']; ?>";

    function catDone() {
        var context;
        context = document.getElementById('cat-image').getContext('2d');
        context.drawImage(catImg, 20, 20, 130, 100);
        ... etc ...

        callback();  /// callback is invoked here
    }
}
```

Now we can do this:

```
drawCatWave(drawCatSquare);
```

Here `drawCatWave()` is called first, when image has loaded and image is drawn the `drawCatSquare()` is called. You can of course replace the callback function with any other function you want to call.

Hope this helps.